# NASM Assembly Print Error

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I was trying to build a very small compiler and so,

`print "Hello world"` becomes

```
SECTION .data
DAT0:
    db "Hello world"
SECTION .text
global _main
extern _printf

_main:
push DAT0
call _printf
add esp, 4

ret 0
```

Which when assembled & linked correctly prints **Hello world**.
Now, when I have two print statements,

```
print "Hello world"
print "Hey!"
```

it generates:

```
SECTION .data
DAT0:
    db "Hello world"
DAT1:
    db "Hey!"

SECTION .text
global _main
extern _printf

_main:
push DAT0
call _printf
add esp, 4

push DAT1
call _printf
add esp, 4

ret 0
```

This prints **Hello worldHey!Hey!**

What my question is why is the text **Hey!** being printed twice. What exactly am I doing
wrong? If it matters, I compiled this code using NASM and MinGW (on Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your strings ASCIIZ, that is: append a byte with value 0 after the string. The `printf()` function uses C-style strings.

So the string pointed by DAT0 is really `Hello worldHey!` Probably there is some zero bytes after "Hey!" to separate sections in the executable.

```
SECTION .data
DAT0:
    db "Hello world",0
DAT1:
    db "Hey!",0
```